# Is it negatively viewed by PhD programs if I completed my masters in 3 years instead of the standard duration of 2 years?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, mathematics, masters, statistics

I am doing my masters in Mathematics in Germany and I wanted to switch my major area from Geometry to Probability Theory after my first year, so that after my masters I can get a PhD in Statistics.

This would mean that I would finish my master's degree in 3 years instead of 2. Is that negatively viewed by graduate admissions committees in US / Europe?

Edit 1: The candidate must write their masters thesis in the major area and also get  more than a certain number of credit points in the major area

Edit 2: I might be getting the opportunity to be a TA in the stochastics department if I do take another year. So money might not be ab issue(except maybe in the mid semester break)

Comment: If you can explain why it took longer, it should be no problem, and maybe even speak in your favor.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/67612/writing-a-masters-thesis-for-2-years-is-that-appropriate Answers to this question might also be relevant

Answer (score 1):

A Master's in Mathematics is presumably what is necessary for a PhD in Statistics (check with universities you'll apply to): **There's no need to switch**. It'll cost time and money. Instead, change the classes you'll take as soon as possible.

Bureaucrats are looking to tick-boxes: They'll presumably be looking for a undergraduate-, postgraduate-degree, or both in Mathematics. They'll likely not consider the classes you took.

A PhD supervisor may be interested in the courses you've taken. Their opinions will vary considerably. Get in touch with some candidate supervisors and ask them.

To a supervisor, a Master's with fifty percent more classes may make you more appealing to a candidate with fewer classes. But, it isn't necessary, so I'd suggest you don't give-up a year. You can learn whatever you don't know during your PhD.

Comment: This would probably be more suitable to answer the OP's [other question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/154956/68109).

Comment: This might result in me not being able to take as many courses in stochastics and other applied fields(data science/computational biology) as one has to earn greater than a certain amount of credits in the major area. Also I would get the chance to do research in stochastics VS doing research in differential geometry. It seems to me that the former might be of greater value when applying for a PhD in statistics

Comment: Also I might be getting the opportunity to be a TA for the stochastics department in the 3rd year. So money will not be an issue(except maybe in the mid semester break) However the loss of time is definitely valid

Comment: @user385655 (I've edited upon reading your comments.) I note: Fewer classes doesn't necessarily matter. Is it necessary to major in an area at your institute?

Comment: The major area is the one in which you are supposed to write your master's thesis in and get over a certain number of credit points

Comment: @user385655 Are _supposed to_ or _must_? Having a master's thesis in the domain of your PhD may be useful. (Equally, having broader knowledge is useful too.)

Comment: You must write the masters thesis in your major area

Comment: I think some caution is needed here. At some departments (for example in Sweden), you are required to have a certain amount of courses in statistics to be eligible for the PhD program. So yes, having a master’s degree in mathematics is certainly helpful when studying PhD level probability theory, but you would be immediately disqualified by the recruiting committee. Bureaucrats indeed like to check tick boxes, and at some places a mathematics MSc wouldn’t let you tick the eligibility box.

Comment: @hejseb The opening line of my answer was intended to deal with exactly that. (I'll edit to clarify.)

Comment: @user385655 That's more relevant. Maybe edit your question to clarify some of these details. To determine relevance a PhD, ask candidate supervisors.